# How to retrieve zero fill column from mysql via python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-python, zerofill

I have a table in mysql as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `province` (
  `pid` int(2) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `pname` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `family` int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `population` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `male` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `female` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_persian_ci
```

note that first column (pid) is zero fill column
and the data in the table(province) is as below:

```
=========================================
|pid|pname|family|population|male|female|
=========================================
|02 | 'A' |  12  |    20    |  8 |   5  |
=========================================
|03 | 'B' |  25  |    20    |  7 |   6  |
=========================================
|05 | 'c' |  34  |     5    |  7 |   9  |
=========================================
```

I want to retrieve pid column via python so my python code is:

```
import mysql.connector

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = []
    res = []
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='mehdi', password='mehdi', host='127.0.0.1', database='cra_db')
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    qrystr = 'SELECT pid FROM province;'
    cursor.execute(qrystr)
    print(cursor.fetchall())
    cnx.close()
```

but when i run this python code this Exception occurred:

returned a result with an error set
  File "C:\Users\M_Parastar\Desktop\New folder\ttt.py", line 11, in 
    print(cursor.fetchall())

---

Do you have any idea how to retrieve zero fill column via python??

Answer (score 0):

The cursor returns an iterable python object, replace "print(cursor.fetchall())" with "for rows in cursor: print (rows)".  Visit [Connector/Python API Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor.html)